# SharePoint 2010 how to duplicate add document link on sharepoint list

Tags: 2010, javascript, navigation, document

How to duplicate add document link on a SharePoint list?

I am planning to put the **"add document"** link both on the top and bottom of the SharePoint list as well as the **"navigation link"** next and previous".

This code can relocate the add document on top of the list

```
<script>

var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE"); 
var ListList = "";
for (var i=x.length-1; i>0; i-- ) 
{
// find just the tables that are list web parts (have a "summary" element)
if (x[i].summary)
{
    try {
    // Now find the "add new" rows
    var theTable = x[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling;
    // but if the table is the paging table (next / previous) then get the next table
    if (theTable.innerHTML.indexOf("ms-bottompaging") > 0)
    {
        theTable = x[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling;
    }
    // hide the unneeded horizontal line
    theTable.rows[0].style.display="none";
    // hide the extra blank space
    theTable.rows[2].style.display="none";
    // move the table    
    var theContainer = x[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    theContainer.parentNode.insertBefore(theTable,theContainer);
    }
    catch (err123) {}
} 
}
</script>
```

Comment: i hope some one will answer this someday :(